# How to get LatLng position by clicking the maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps, coordinates

I am using `google_maps_flutter` to show the maps of user location, I come up with an idea where user can click anything in maps and show the the coordinates they clicked. What I mean with the coordinates here is Lat and Lng position that the click from the maps. Is that possible to do that ? and are there some articles as guide for me to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onTap` callback of `GoogleMap` widget like below to get coordinates from map where use clicks.

```
GoogleMap(
  onTap: (LatLng latLng) {
    final lat = latLng.latitude;
    final long = latLng.longitude;
  },
);
```